# SVG scaling issue

Tags: javascript, svg, scale

Thank you in advance. The stackoverflow community is such a great resource. Thanks everyone for helping out.

Please see the pen indicated below.

I am dynamically animating SVG elements as needed.

My problem is that I want the animation to take place where the item is. In this example however, the element slides down and to the right. Is there a command that scales the element from the center out?

http://codepen.io/JoeyCinAZ/pen/JBKoy

```
//create an <animate> element that will allow for a blinking effect
var alert = document.createElementNS(xmlns, 'animateTransform');
alert.setAttribute('attributeName', 'transform');
alert.setAttribute('type', 'scale');
alert.setAttribute('from', '1');
alert.setAttribute('to', '2');
alert.setAttribute('begin', '0s');
alert.setAttribute('dur', '3s');
alert.setAttribute('repeatCount', '3');
```

Comment: Why not also translate it in the opposite direction to appear as if it's scaling from the center?

Comment: I'm sure that this problem ***does not*** need you to post such a full demo. It need just a simple SVG code without any JS involved. That's how you prepare a good question ***focusing*** directly and mainly to the problem.

Comment: Thank you @KingKing for the feedback. I am still new to stackoverflow, and have seen many posts ask for a demo. I see your point, and will apply to future questions.

Comment: your problem is in fact to set the scaling origin. You can search for *scaling SVG at center* or *SVG scaling center origin*, ... However looks like you have more problems than just that. I've just tried it in Chrome and it does not work. It just works *once* in Maxthon...

Comment: And @tenub, I'm trying your suggestion too. I love programming and how there are often multiple ways to solve the same problem.